# Xcode iOS: "Reported test case event for non-suite test object"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I've inherited an Obj-C project, and started adding some tests for new code.  However, when I try to run the first test I've added, I get a strange error message that I can't seem to find any information for:

```
2017-05-29 12:12:24.636 AppName[7143:146141] *** Assertion failure in -[XCTestObservationCenter _testCaseDidStart:], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/XCTest_Sim/XCTest-12124/Sources/XCTestFramework/Observation/XCTestObservationCenter.m:253
<unknown>:0: error: TestClassTests : Reported test case event for non-suite test object -[(null) testMethod]
```

The funny thing is, it shows the nice green checkmark, even though there's this error.  There's also a whole stack trace that goes along with it which I'm happy to add if anybody has any ideas.

```
Test Suite 'TestClass' failed at 2017-05-29 12:12:24.664.
 Executed 0 tests, with 1 failure (1 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.029) seconds
Test Suite 'AppNameTests.xctest' failed at 2017-05-29 12:12:24.665.
 Executed 0 tests, with 1 failure (1 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.031) seconds
Test Suite 'All tests' failed at 2017-05-29 12:12:24.666.
 Executed 0 tests, with 1 failure (1 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.032) seconds
```

So my interpretation of this message is that my test function doesn't seem to be in the "test suite", though I was under the impression that the test suite is automatically generated from my source!  Xcode even shows my test function in the tests tab just fine.  I don't think I'm doing anything out of the ordinary here, though it's possible there's some hidden cruft in the project file I inherited.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Could you share some code of your test case?

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same error. I have no idea about this error and error message, so I begin to delete code in my test case to find the source reason of this error.

```
@interface MyTests : XCTestCase
@property (nonatomic, strong) id class;
@end

@implementation MyTests
- (void)testNothing {
}
@end
```

Look the code above, I almost delete every thing in my test case, but error is still existed. Finally, when I delete `@property (nonatomic, strong) id class;`, error is gone! Then I put my real test code back, everything is fine, no error.

I don't know the reason of this error, it's weired...